# gulp-rev-collector doesn't work

Tags: javascript, gulp

I use gulp-rev and gulp-rev-collector to replace urls. I've tried lots of ways but it didn't work.

Here's my 
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z24n5.png)

here's my code

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean');
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    revAppend = require('gulp-rev-append'),
    revCollector = require('gulp-rev-collector');

gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('src/*.css')
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('rev'));

});

gulp.task('concat', function() {
    gulp.src('app/*.css')
        .pipe(concat('all.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));

});

gulp.task('rev', function() {
    gulp.src(['rev/*.json','src/*.html'])
        .pipe(revCollector())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'))
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(clean());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this problem.It turns out that the url in HTML is 'copyCss.css',but in file 'rev-manifest.json', key is 'copyCss.min.css'.So it doesn't match.